# How do I get a SparkSession object from inside a MapFunction on a dataframe?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a SparkSession handle, which I use to create a dataframe, in my main function in Java.

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.createDataFrame(...)
```

I then use the MapFunction as follows

```
ds.MapFunction((Row, Integer) -> row {
        SparkSession sparkSession1 = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate();
        ...
```

However, this results in the exception "A master URL must be set in your configuration". This seems to work fine in local, but I need it to run on a cluster, where the call to getOrCreate, inside the main function succeeds, but fails in the MapFunction. What is the right way to get a handle to the SparkSession inside the Mapfunction?

Comment: You should not do that, it's wrong (you shouldn't be accessing sparksession or spark context in mapping functions). Please describe what you're trying to do for the right solutions to be suggested.

Comment: Let us say I wanted to parallelize the read operations, maybe sparkSession.read("/some/hdfs/path") inside the Mapfunction. Is there a way to achieve that without accessing sparkSession inside the mapping function?

Comment: I'd be speculating without the real scenario. But how about flattening/exploding your collection?

Comment: Not sure I understood the exploding part. Let us say I have got a list of thousands of files in hdfs, which I need to read and do some processing on each file. And each file needs a call to sparkSession.read. That is the actual scenario

Comment: This is all depending on your data. If you meant to create a new spark job in your mapping function, then you can read whole text files and map to lines in your function. But you could just as well read lines from `"/some/hdfs/*"`. Spark is designed to efficiently parallelize executions like that. If you think you really need to create multiple jobs, then maybe you have to send multiple jobs in parallel (using different threads) from your driver. This is tricky, you need to pay attention to your scheduler configuration.